# Prevent pop-up form control background color from flashing white when changing control properties via Option click

Tags: vba, ms-access, properties, controls

In MS-Access 2010, I have a pop-up user form with a number of controls whose caption and/or enabled properties change via VBA when a option button is clicked.  These controls have their back style is set to transparent so the form's background shows through.

When I click one of the two option buttons the background color of the controls I am changing momentarily flashes to a solid white. This happens for about 1/10th second and is distracting and annoying.  How do I prevent this from happening?

I have tried the the following to no avail:

```
 Private Sub fraMode_Click()
      Application.Echo False
      With Me.fraMode
           If .Value = 1 Then
                Call InitAdd    'Change controls to Add
           Else
                Call InitDel    'Change controls to Delete
           End If
      End Width
      Application.Echo True
 End Sub
```

I have also tried moving `Application.Echo False ... Application.Echo True` to different events with no success.

The following show what is being happening:

[image: Form-Normal] and [image: Form-Flash]

Comment: I couldn't duplicate the problem.  try deleting the option group control and then rebuilding it and see if the problem mysteriously is fixed.

Comment: Try setting the `.Painting` property of the form to false and revert it to true once done.

Comment: I think this just normal behavior. I've come across it so I had to set the control background color to match the form's to avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have discovered what is happening.  In this case, the form background is a stretched PNG image that gives the gradient effect from top to bottom.  My detail back color is white.  So when I click on one of the option buttons those items which are changing momentarily show the detail back color.  I can change the detail back color to something approaching the image color but since the image is a gradient there is no way to mitigate the effect entirely.  The only way to prevent this effect would be to eliminate the background image and set the detail back color to a solid blue.